# wagmi TypeError: zustand_vanilla__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...) is not a function

Tags: wagmi

I'm on wagmi 0.6.8. I get this error when doing

```
import {
  WagmiConfig,
  createClient,
  configureChains,
  defaultChains,
  chain
} from 'wagmi'

const { chains, provider, webSocketProvider } = configureChains(
  [chain.mainnet],
  [publicProvider()],
)

const client = createClient({
  autoConnect: true,
  provider,
  webSocketProvider,
})
```

Viewing in my localhost. I seem to remember this working fine not too long ago.

```
TypeError: zustand_vanilla__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...) is not a function
new Client
node_modules/@wagmi/core/dist/getProvider-5b4b62c3.esm.js:825
  822 | } // Create store
  823 | 
  824 | 
> 825 | this.store = create(subscribeWithSelector(persist(() => ({
      | ^  
  826 |   connectors: typeof connectors === 'function' ? connectors() : connectors,
  827 |   provider: this.getProvider({
  828 |     chainId: _chainId
View compiled
createClient
node_modules/@wagmi/core/dist/getProvider-5b4b62c3.esm.js:1076
  1073 | 
  1074 | let client;
  1075 | function createClient(config) {
> 1076 |   const client_ = new Client(config);
  1077 |   client = client_;
  1078 |   return client_;
  1079 | }
View compiled
createClient
node_modules/wagmi/dist/wagmi.esm.js:695
  692 |   }) : undefined,
  693 |   ...config
  694 | } = _ref;
> 695 | const client = createClient$1(config);
      | ^  
  696 | if (persister) persistQueryClient({
  697 |   queryClient,
  698 |   persister,
View compiled
Module.<anonymous>
src/App.tsx:28
  25 |   [publicProvider()],
  26 | )
  27 | 
> 28 | const client = createClient({
  29 |   autoConnect: true,
  30 |   provider,
  31 |   webSocketProvider,
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by downgrading zustand as such:

```
 "zustand@npm:^4.0.0":
-  version: 4.3.1
-  resolution: "zustand@npm:4.3.1"
+  version: 4.1.4
+  resolution: "zustand@npm:4.1.4"
   dependencies:
     use-sync-external-store: 1.2.0
   peerDependencies:
@@ -19990,6 +20141,6 @@ __metadata:
       optional: true
     react:
       optional: true
-  checksum: bc35ebdfb2028e33d112ec113d77c95bdc3b693b3c2d78eacdc40017cf8f7f32934a49213aab3ee5e3767b44869bd306da171e6438b89fbc78417b419725e895
+  checksum: a9ceb7849ebf407d31a6121be09acfb041324f6f45ca9a3f62ab85e2d840d0f48f157abd99ed7b9e08b96ebb4e15480b4a196ed8b1df8a5a9a2ba9afd7c639a7
   languageName: node
   linkType: hard
```